# Apache Solr and Lucene PDF search

Tags: solr, lucene

I want to search for some text in **PDF**, **DOC**, **JPG** file.
I have idea of `lucene` how to extract data from **PDF** and **DOC** and create index on full content.

I know `Solr` and `Lucene` has some **highlight** feature but I am wondering if `Solr` or `lucene` **highlight** matched results in **PDF** or **DOC** itself and displaying it to user.

Does `Solr` or `Lucene` has this functionality?

Comment: Yes its possible refer this [document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Highlighting).